# Import a .csv that contains ',' within strings into R

Tags: r, csv, import

I have large .csv files with thousands of rows of:

```
    key                      ,time                     ,abs-time                 ,value                    ,
actinic-lights.light-1   ,0                        ,"Sep 28, 2021 6:59:59 AM",                         
actinic-lights.light-1   ,0.000278                 ,"Sep 28, 2021 6:59:59 AM",0                        
actinic-lights.light-1   ,0.701389                 ,"Sep 28, 2021 7:04:11 AM",0.5001                   
actinic-lights.light-1   ,1.229167                 ,"Sep 28, 2021 7:07:21 AM",1.5004                   
actinic-lights.light-1   ,1.606389                 ,"Sep 28, 2021 7:09:37 AM",2.5002                   
actinic-lights.light-1   ,1.925833                 ,"Sep 28, 2021 7:11:32 AM",3.5007
```

that contain an abs-time date column in the format:
`Sep 28, 2021 9:09:59 AM`

The ',' is causing my import into R to fail because

`data.table::fread` is interpreting the ',' within the date as a data separator.
Does anyone have a solution?
thanks Doug

Comment: If your data is really CSV (as you commented in my since-deleted answer), then please provide a CSV example, we can't help with a file that is mis-represented in the question. Assuming you can reproduce the problem with the first few rows of the file (e.g., `read.csv(... nrows=4)`), then just post the top 5 lines of the raw file contents in a code block above and I'm hoping we can help. If you need specific lines from the file to trigger the problem, then you might need to use `Notepad` (or some other text editor) to concoct a simple reproducible example here on SO.

Comment: Hi @r2evans; I am struggling with the StackOverflow interface.  We determined the issue relates to exporting the .csv data files via Windows, rather than directly from Linux (or from MacOS).  In the sample above we see that after Windows export the dates are formatted as "Sep 28, 2021 9:09:59 AM", instead of the original Linux format of 28-Sep-2021 6:59:59 AM.

Comment: If I do `read.csv(text="...")`, it parses perfectly fine as-is, though the comma after `value` is causing an extra (all-`NA`) column to be created. If I do `fread(text="...")`, it *incorrectly* sees five fields in the first row (due to the trailing comma) and then projects that on to all other rows, splitting the `abs-time` column (which seems like a bug in `data.table::fread`, but they have other issues with CSV standards, so perhaps we can add it to the list); if I remove the errant comma, `fread` parses it perfectly fine. Either way, remove the extra comma or switch to `read.csv`.

Comment: Thanks.  We re-exported to avoid the errant comma. We are using data.table::fread for other reasons as part of a bigger import function.